# How to group records from single partition using window for time T to single record, each record having the same key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, stream-processing

Let's say I have an event stream.

R1 - {"abc": "value 1"}

R2 - {"abc": "value 2"}

R3 - {"abc": "value 3"}

R4 - {"abc": "value 4"}

in a single partition. I want a derived event stream from the above stream to have event like

{"abc": ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3", "value 4"]}

given each record 
with the same key is available in the topic already.

How can I do that using aggregation and groupByKey in Kafka Stream API?

Comment: What have you tried already? You can start from: https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html

Comment: Yes. I have, but I am unable to make it work. I haven't tried it in the coding, but stream processing is not about coding it, it is about understanding it. So I am only curious if one can do that.

Comment: In documentation you can find section with example regarding windowing: (https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing), aggregating (https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#aggregating) and windowing final results (https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#window-final-results). It can be good to start from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for JSON Event stream, you can try something like following:

```
KTable<Windowed<String>, JsonNode> timeWindowedAggregatedStream = stream.groupByKey().windowedBy(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
    .aggregate(
        () -> objectMapper::createObjectNode, /* initializer */
        (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> {
            final JsonNode element = value.has(fieldName) && value.get(fieldName) != null ? value.get(fieldName) : null;

        final ArrayNode arrayNode = aggregate == null || aggregate.get(fieldName) != null
                ? (ArrayNode) aggregate.get(fieldName)
                : mapper.createArrayNode();

        arrayNode.add(element);
        // TO remove duplicates
        Stream<Object> elementStream = IntStream.range(0, arrayNode.size()).mapToObj(arrayNode::get);
        Set<Object> arrayAsSet = elementStream.collect(Collectors.toSet());
        ObjectNode aggregateNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
        ArrayNode uniqueArrayNode = mapper.valueToTree(arrayAsSet);
        aggregate.set(fieldName, uniqueArrayNode); 
        return aggregate;
} , /* adder */
        Materialized.<String, JsonNode, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("time-windowed-aggregated-stream-store") /* state store name */
        .withValueSerde(jsonNodeSerde)); /* serde for aggregate value */
```